# Getting the current locale in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, locale

In Gwt i'm setting the locale to use in `<meta name="gwt:property" content="locale=${pageContext.request.locale}">`. The locale is managed by Spring with the `LocaleChangeInterceptor` and that is working fine.

For a form i want to load the available countries into a Gwt listbox from a server. Ofcourse i want the country names in the correct language so i created a service method `void getCountryCodes(String language, AsyncCallback<Map<String, String>> async)`. That code also works correct when i insert the language as 'nl' or 'en' for dutch or english.

My last piece of this puzzle is to get the locale my GWT application is running in. I tried using GwtLocale and with LocaleInfo, but both can not give me the information to find the current language i'm running in.

Can anyone help me in finding the correct way for getting the language my gwt application is running in?

Thank you for all your effort.

Comment: I found similar question,it might help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727/how-to-get-locale-information-on-a-gwt-application

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106973/how-to-get-the-current-locale-in-gwt-using-localeinfo

Comment: Thanks all for helping. The actual problem was that i'm not passing the locale correct. Using `LocalInfo.getCurrentLocale().getLocaleName()` worked like a charm.

Comment: @Martin - If you read the question you linked to, it is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In GWT:

```
String locale = LocaleInfo.getCurrentLocale().getLocaleName();
```

Comment: Using this solution I get the value "default" even though my JSP sets correctly "en_US" using <meta name="gwt:property" content="locale=<%= request.getLocale() %>">, any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can put locale info additionally in hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" value="${pageContext.request.locale}" id="springlocale"/>
```

and obtain it on client side

```
String locale = (InputElement) (Element) DOM.getElementById("springlocale").value
```